# How to declare dependency on other ROS package for launch files

Tags: ros, package.xml, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm creating a package that exclusively uses launch files from other ROS packages. In other words, I'm not creating any nodes I'm just making a package to conveniently group and launch nodes from other packages. How am I supposed to declare those other ROS packages as dependencies, if I do at all? Is it in the `package.xml` using the `<run_depend>` or some other tag such as `<exec_depend>`?

I've checked [REP 140](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#exec-depend-multiple), [REP 127](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#run-depend-multiple), the [`package.xml` wiki entry](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml), and [Roslaunch tips for large projects](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects) and I'm not 100% how to do it. From what I can tell, REP 140 says to use `<exec_depend>` for

> ...packages providing shared libraries,
> executable commands, Python modules,
> launch scripts or any other files
> required for running your package.

which, to me, sounds like if I want to use the launch files from another package then I should declare that package as a dependency in `package.xml` using `<exec_depend>`.

So, again, the question is how am I supposed to declare those other ROS packages as dependencies, if I do at all?

Edit: I should have tested the `<exec_depend>` tag before mentioning it because I get the following error:

```
The manifest (with format version 1) must not contain the following tags: exec_depend
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264270/how-to-declare-dependency-on-other-ros-package-for-launch-files/) by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6155 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-20**:
REP-140 describes package format version 2, and specifies that you should declare your package.xml as version 2 in the opening package tag at the top, with `<package format="2">` ( http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#package-format-2 )

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-20**:
That explains why I was getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've found the right documentation. Note that REP-127 is for the older package format 1, and REP-140 is for package.xml format version 2.

Version 1 is still the default; if you want to use version 2, you must have `<package format="2">` at the top of your package.xml

In version 1, `<run_depend>` is the correct tag for launch file dependencies.

In version 2, `<exec_depend>` is the correct tag for launch file dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-20**:
Perfect, thanks. This way makes more sense.